# Trace operator in Least Squares Classification

Tags: machine-learning, least-squares

I am reading Bishop's PRML book and got a bit stuck with equation 4.15 in the part that covers application of least squares method in classification:

$E_D(\tilde{\mathbf{W}}) = \frac{1}{2}Tr\{(\tilde{\mathbf{X}}\tilde{\mathbf{W}}-\mathbf{T})^T(\tilde{\mathbf{X}}\tilde{\mathbf{W}}-\mathbf{T})\}$

What is the trace operator doing in the matrix/vector sum of least squares?  Can someone provide a simple and intuitive example that illustrates the squared error and trace operator connection?

Thank you very much in advance!

Vlad

Comment: Why was the answer deleted?  :-)  I was just about to thank the responder!

Comment: My explanation was not correct (I am the one who deleted my own answer). I will try to write a better one if somebody else does not do it in the meantime.

Comment: Thanks, looking forward!  Although your explanation gave me enough to figure it out.  Just writing out a simple two by two case and applying trace operator to it is sufficient for illustration, all cross term products vanish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is simply a matrix form of the sum-of-squares error function. To see this, note that:

1. The rows of $\tilde{\mathbf{X}} \tilde{\mathbf{W}}$ are your predictions (one row per sample);
2. Thus, the entries of $\tilde{\mathbf{X}} \tilde{\mathbf{W}} - \mathbf{T}$ are the errors, where the row indicates which sample we're viewing, *and the column which component of that sample*;
3. The $i$-th diagonal entry of $\mathbf{A}^T \mathbf{A}$ is the sum of the squared elements of the $i$-th column. So, the $i$-th diagonal entry of $(\tilde{\mathbf{X}} \tilde{\mathbf{W}} - \mathbf{T})^T (\tilde{\mathbf{X}} \tilde{\mathbf{W}} - \mathbf{T})$ is the sum of the squared errors made in the $i$-th component, taken over all samples;
4. At the end, we apply the trace operator to sum up the diagonal entries (errors).

The factor of $\frac 1 2$ is there to make things simpler when the expression is differentiated.

Answer (score -1):

The trace here is the [Frobenius inner product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_inner_product) and the function to be minimized is a squared (Frobenius) norm.